# How to measure elapsed time without being affected by changes in system time

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I want to measure elapsed time in seconds. With `std::chrono::steady_clock` I do it. However it suffers from system time changes.

Wasn't steady_clock supposed to not being affected by changes in system time?

How can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <time.h>

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

/* Change system time */
std::time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
tnow -= 20;
std::cout << "stime: " << stime(&tnow) << std::endl;
/********************************************************/

sleep(5);
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::cout << "ELAPSED: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t2-t).count() << std::endl;
```

This results:

```
stime: 0
ELAPSED: -15
```

What I wanted to get was:

```
ELAPSED: 5
```

**Edit:**

I have added C tag, because it seems that it is a kernel (or buildroot of board) bug. So, how could I achieve this without `chrono`? I mean, in a straight way (without having to watch system time changes).

How was the people living before chrono?

Comment: What compiler is this? I remember having problems with steady_clcok on the Microsoft compiler. Not sure if they've been fixed.

Comment: @JasperKent gcc

Comment: Regarding to your edit, you can use clock() function in time.h which supposed to measure elapsed CPU clock time.

Comment: I've removed the C tag because this is still a C++ question.

Comment: @JohnKugelman why? The code that I have tried is C++, but what I am asking for is, as title suggests, how to achieve that. C-solution is also welcome.

Comment: @unlut, at least for this example it does not work, since clock does not count sleep().

Comment: Questions should rarely be tagged with both. If you're compiling with a C++ compiler you should usually just tag with C++. Answerers know that they can answer with C-like answers, you don't have to tag with C to allow it. For a more in-depth discussion see: [Question is tagged both "c" and "c++", but has no reason to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358560/question-is-tagged-both-c-and-c-but-has-no-reason-to-be).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can file a bug with your vendor.

[From the standard:](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.steady#1)

> Objects of class `steady_­clock` represent clocks for which values of
> `time_­point` never decrease as physical time advances and for which
> values of `time_­point` advance at a steady rate relative to real
> time. That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

If you can find a reliable source of monotonic time on your system, you can easily wrap that source in a custom `chrono::clock` and subsequently still make use of the type-safe chrono system.  For example:

```
#include <chrono>

struct MyClock
{
    using duration                  = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using rep                       = duration::rep;
    using period                    = duration::period;
    using time_point                = std::chrono::time_point<MyClock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = true;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        timespec ts;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
        return time_point{seconds{ts.tv_sec} + nanoseconds{ts.tv_nsec}};
    }
};
```

Now you can say things like:

```
MyClock::time_point t = MyClock::now();
// ...
MyClock::time_point t2 = MyClock::now();
std::cout << "ELAPSED: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t2-t).count() << std::endl;
```